# Validate an authToken

Tags: java, spring-security, websocket

Got a websocket - see the authToken in the Cookie, in Java Spring how do you validate this authToken?  I understand this authToken is passed down from the http layer to the websocket so I'm trying to validate that the websocket is being opened by our app and not by some other source.

```
Headers for Websocket:  
GET ws://localhost:9999/somePath/websocket HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:9999  
Connection: Upgrade  
Pragma: no-cache  
Cache-Control: no-cache  
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36  
Upgrade: websocket  
Origin: http://localhost  
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br  
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9  
Cookie: authToken=elFKMk5TckR0ZUNvdnZySUJxc2ZMdz09OklEZENrRFRySkp0U0ltVFdKU1RIZVE9PQ  
Sec-WebSocket-Key: e//VDAjHSRjE810tCbIEyw==  
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits  
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: v10.stomp, v11.stomp, v12.stomp
```

I would like to validate that authToken in the HttpHandshakeInterceptor.beforeHandshake

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
registry.addEndpoint(stompEndPoint).addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor()).setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();

public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor
Override
public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler wsHandler, Map attributes) throws Exception {

    if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
        ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
        attributes.put("sessionId", session.getId());
        // validate token logic

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what service you authenticate against. That service will tell you if the token is valid.

Comment: Its spring-security - I would think there would be something like SecurityManger.isValidToken(authToken).   In my case the Websocket is opened up to another server (the location of beforeHandshake in the code above), so I need to validate the authToken back to server where all the login is happening - getting back to that server is easy, but what to call to authenticate has me confused.